# NPM throws error on "audit fix" - Configured registry is not supported

Tags: npm, npm-audit, npm-config

Since last night i'm getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOAUDIT
npm ERR! audit Your configured registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/) does not support audit requests.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ransinha/.npm/_logs/2018-11-28T18_19_35_432Z-debug.log
```

I have not made any recent changes. https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/689 suggests changeing in config.yaml file. I don't see any config.yaml file in my folder. I'm not using verdaccio also. Not sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

Update:
The npm audit shows the following:

```
                   === npm audit security report ===
```

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│                                Manual Review                                │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
┌───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Critical      │ Malicious Package                                            │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Package       │ flatmap-stream                                               │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Dependency of │ nodemon [dev]                                                │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Path          │ nodemon > pstree.remy > ps-tree > event-stream >             │
│               │ flatmap-stream                                               │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/737                       │

Comment: what does `npm audit` show

Comment: Which Npm version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based the more info link, you are advised to use event-stream@3.3.4

To do this:

1, Delete the node_modules folder of flatmap-stream

2, Edit package-lock.json file, i think under ps_tree object and add/edit the dependencies as shown below:

```
"requires": {
    "event-stream": "~3.3.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "event-stream": {
        "version": "3.3.4"
    }
}
```

Run npm install again, this should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Delete `package-lock.json` and do `npm i` works for me.