# NPM-AUDIT find to high vulnerabilities. What am I supposed to do?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-audit, angular-devkit

`npm audit` run on my project and got me this

> High            Command Injection
>   Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]
>
> Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > @ngtools/webpack >
>   tree-kill
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1432
>
> High            Command Injection
>
> Package         tree-kill
>
> Patched in      >=1.2.2
>
> Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]
>
> Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > tree-kill
>
> More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1432

**Tree-kill** needs to be updated, but is a dep of angular, not mine. So what? Need to wait that angular-team update its own package.json to a newer version of tree-kill?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can fix this without waiting for a new version of the package `@angular-devkit/build-angular`.

Just do the following steps:

1. Update your `package.json` file by adding `resolutions` section with proper version of package `tree-kill`:

```
"resolutions": {
  "tree-kill": "1.2.2"
}
```

2. Update your `package-lock.json` by running command:

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

3. Reinstall NPM packages in your project:

```
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

Run `npm audit` to check that your project does not have anymore this problem. And don't forget to commit modified files `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

More information about [NPM Force Resolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-force-resolutions).

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem today and I fixed it by:

1. delete the tree-kill package from the node_modules folder.
2. delete the package-lock.json file.
3. go to the @angular-devkit/build-angular folder in the node_modules folder and edit the package.json file; change tree-kill version from 1.2.1 to 1.2.2
4. go to @ngtools/webpack folder in the node_modules folder and do the same as step 3.

run npm install after that.

Comment: So by this fix, I have to keep node_modules folder with Git right?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question right, but you need to commit the new changes after the new installation.

Comment: edit manually your dependencies is not a good idea, as doing a new installation of the project will represent the issue

Comment: @Loki no! node_modules is a compilation of all binaries from dependencies. Much like the .m2/repository folder for Maven. The codebase does not need it and NPM _should_ resolve dependencies for every person cloning the repo. That's why you keep the package.json (and the package-lock when you run a dependency scanner, like in github). Also, creating an unsupported mod of the dependency seems like a recipe for disaster once you update Angular, clone it on another place, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem too and after some researchs, i found something:

[NPM throws error on "audit fix" - Configured registry is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53525845/npm-throws-error-on-audit-fix-configured-registry-is-not-supported)

Of course, it's about an other problem but, by adapting the solution given there, it resolved my problem.

So :

- Delete the node_modules folder of tree-kill
- Edit package-lock.json file like it's done but with tree-kill module instead.
- Don't forget to run **npm install** at the end

I hope i've been clear enough.

Comment: How could I edit the package-lock.json in the second step if it was supposed to be deleted when deleting the node_modules folder of tree-kill in the step 1?

Answer (score 2):

Check the GitHub repo to see if a fix is being worked on. I found this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16629 and a pull request (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/15894) which removes the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to package.json

```
"resolutions": {
"tree-kill":"1.2.2"
}
```

Remove all node modules:

```
rm -r node_modules
```

Update package-lock.json for new version 1.2.2 as :

```
npx npm-force-resolutions
```

Now install node modules:

```
npm install
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the tree-kill package from the node_modules folder & Delete
   the package-lock.json file.
2. Find @angular-devkit/build-angular
   folder in the node_modules folder and edit the package.json file;
       change    tree-kill version from 1.2.1 to 1.2.2
   Find @ngtools/webpack
   in the    node_modules folder and edit the package.json file; 
       change    tree-kill version from 1.2.1 to 1.2.2
3. run npm install.

Answer (score 0):

Update your @angular-devkit/build-angular version in package.json to below:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.10"
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting node_modules and reinstalling helps without any issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).