# How to manually fix the vulnerabilities shown during npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am a beginner to NodeJS and during the installation of packages I encountered some vulnerabilities error. I have encountered a few errors previously as well. And which were fixed by simply updating the packages. Also, 'npm audit fix' didn't help. Following is the result of 'npm audit'. Can anyone tell me, how can I update these dependencies manually?

```
                       === npm audit security report ===                        


                             Manual Review                                  
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


      High            Command Injection                                             

      Package         tree-kill                                                     

      Patched in      >=1.2.2                                                       

      Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]                           

      Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > @ngtools/webpack > tree-kill  

      More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1432                             


      High            Command Injection                                             

      Package         tree-kill                                                     

      Patched in      >=1.2.2                                                       

      Dependency of   @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]                           

      Path            @angular-devkit/build-angular > tree-kill                     

      More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1432                             

    found 2 high severity vulnerabilities in 16547 scanned packages
      2 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

Also, can I update the 'tree-kill' package under the path '@angular-devkit/build-angular > @ngtools/webpack > tree-kill' and '@angular-devkit/build-angular > tree-kill' manually? If Yes, then how do I do it?

npm version - 6.12.1
node version - 12.13.1

Thank You for helping!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707917/2183775 Solved to me.